# Swift 3 write data to location for iOS 11not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11

I got little problem, I am downloading PDF and saving to location, I am using write method to save to location and everything seems to work on version iOS 10 and below, but I got problem with iOS11, I am getting false from method below, I checked path, and bytes and it is same on both devices.

```
 (try? data.write(to: invoiceFileUrl, options: [.atomic])) != nil
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 let data = NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)

 data?.write(to:invoiceFileUrl, atomically: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply moving the file around? I am guessing you are using URLSession to download said file ( or you should anyway ).

Then you can use `FileManager` to move the temporary file to your documents or whatever desired directory in your app's container.

```
FileManager.default.moveItem(at:temporaryURL, to: destinationURL)
```

In case you prefer using paths there is also:

```
FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: temporaryPath, toPath: destinationPath)
```

Though I personally don't use paths often (anymore) because it can lead to a whole load of inconsistencies and other issues you just don't want to deal with. Whatever backend you have try to move to NSURL or `URL` as quickly as you can with any received data; it'll make your life easier and most importantly more consistent accross foundation API's.

[moveItemAtURL - Foundation documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1414750-moveitematurl?language=objc)